# React - Passing data from external API to CSV file

Tags: reactjs, export-to-csv

I'm trying to pass data from external api and convert it to a CSV file. This is what I have so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";
import Header from './components/header'
import './App.scss'

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      orders: []
    }
    this.getReports = this.getReports.bind(this)
  }

  getReports = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('example.com')
    const ordersData = await response.json()

    this.setState({
      orders: ordersData.data,

    })

    let order = this.state.orders.map(order => ({
      ID: order.id,
      Order_ID: order.order_id,
      Date: order.created,
      Amount: order.total_amount,
      Payment_Provider: order.payments[0].provider_id,
      Payment_ID: order.payments[0].id,
      Refund_Reason: order.reason
    }))

    const objectToCsv = (order) => {

      const csvRows = [];
      const headers = Object.keys(order[0])
      csvRows.push(headers.join(','));

      // console.log(csvRows)

      for (const row of order) {
        const values = headers.map(header => {
          const escaped = ('' + row[header]).replace(/"/g, '\\"')
          return `"${escaped}"`
        })
        csvRows.push(values.join(','))
      }

      return csvRows.join('\n')

    }

    let csvData = objectToCsv(order)

    console.log(csvData)

    // console.log(order)
    // console.log(this.state.orders)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="body">
          {/* <button onClick={this.getReports}>CLICK</button> */}
          <CSVLink data={csvData} onClick={this.getReports}>Click me</CSVLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem I'm facing is that I can't pass the csvData variable to the data attribute in the CsvLink component since the variable is not global. I tried adding another csvData state where I passed the objectToCsv(order) and that stops the error, however when I download the CSV, the content is jiberish. 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: does the `console.log(csvData)` give you the expected result?

Comment: Yes, it's logging the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added the following to my getReports function and removed the csvLink component and I was able to export the data to CSV file, but it's definitely not a nice UX. I still need to work on separating the inputs into columns.

```
const blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' })
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
const a = document.createElement('a')
a.setAttribute('hidden', '')
a.setAttribute('href', url)
a.setAttribute('download', 'download.csv')
document.body.appendChild(a)
a.click()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer...if i want to download some of the columns and rows in the table ....how to do it...please let me know...